# Connecting Parse with FB integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform

I'm creating a chat app, and the user is first taken to the main menu, where they can select "chat" and then be directed to a FB Login feature, after the user logs in with FB, they are supposed to be redirected to a tab bar controller.  However I cannot figure out how to set the programatic segue up so that it takes the user directly to that screen after a successful login.

I don't know if that's why Parse isn't collecting the User Data or not, but I get this warning when running the app:  [10799:60b] Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.  My question is how do I create that segue to my Tab Bar Controller and am I missing something with Parse?

***Here is my AppDelegate.m file:***

```
#import "CCAppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@implementation CCAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXX"
                  clientKey:@"XXXX"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    return wasHandled;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

***And here is my CCLoginViewController.m file:***

```
#import "CCLoginViewController.h"

@interface CCLoginViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end

@implementation CCLoginViewController

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide
{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePictureView.hidden = shouldHide;
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged in.";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
}
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
}
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"You are logged out";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}
-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.loginView.delegate = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";
    self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on [iOS, Facebook Users](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS) you should be calling `FBAppCall` slightly differently:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActiveWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
}
```

The key part you're missing is the `withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]`, which I'm guessing lets Parse know about what Facebook is doing.

I also don't see any Parse query in your code, so some other part of your code must be triggering that warning, somewhere you're doing a query without using a `withBlock:`, which lets it handle the results on a background thread without locking up the UI.